# comparing values to find if it exists or not (VBA)?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets. The first one is already defined and in the other one the user needs to enter values.

Assume column B of both worksheets for the problem. Now when a user enters a value in column B the code should compare it with column B of sheet A. If it exists in the first sheet then program should resume the other operations otherwise an error message should be displayed indicating a non-existing value.

Comment: I would do this with data validation within excel, not VBA. The ongoing process' can be done using worksheet on selection change. If you create a validation, so that it validates against the whole of col B in sheet A, then validation provides a fast way to confirm a 'valid' value.

Comment: You didn't state any problem, can you please provide what you did write until now and clarify what your problems are / where you get errors?

Comment: Unless you can clarify exactly what you're having a problem with, this is going to look like you're asking someone to write your code for you. What have you tried so far and which part of an attempted solution isn't working as you'd expect?

Comment: @Aiken: i am not from programming background and new to VB. So, i was not aware of "iserror" function. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I compare a value entered in column B in `Worksheets("Sheet2")` with the values found in `Range(B1:B10)` in `Worksheets("Sheet1")`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B10")

    If Not Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(Target, rng, 1, False)) Then
            //Value found. Do something...
        Else
            MsgBox "Value not found"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this code needs to be placed in the `Sheet2` module

Comment: Thanx Alex!! this code actually helped me quite a lot! :)